check for nan under --ffast-math
Suppose (while avoiding a night-filling discussion on why) I use -ffast-math and my program does ten Newton iterations. They either converge or by that point a NaN will have occured.
That is what I wish to check. Now chat GPT told me that still the basic math operations will fill the bits of my number (e.g. float, double, float128, ... ) with bits that express the meaning of NaN, but any attempt as to identifying that fact will fail (and I cannot get myself understanding how that would be even possible).
So suppose the program is compiled with -ffast-math and suppose for simplicity that there is a double x in my code and I seek to know whether x is NaN. How do I do this? To me it appears I could simply implement isnan(x) by checking for x to live within limits.
I have also checked this question and Chat-GPT gave me the implementation for double but all these bit-shifts may not work platform-independently and I do not want to end up going as through as having to test isnan implementations.

One of the promises to the compiler for -ffast-math is that NaNs are not going to happen, and so the compiler will generate code that doesn't handle the NaNs that aren't going to happen.  Are you sure that you ought to be using -ffast-math?

If you need this level of precision in your floating point calculations you shouldn't be using -ffast-math.

instead of -ffast-math it might be better to use some of its flags like -fassociative-math and -freciprocal-math

With -ffast-math, calculations are not allowed to produce nan, so the answer is
bool isnan(double) {
  return false;
}

Of course, it is the one supplying the flag making that guarantee, and if it's not really true, very nonsensical results are possible.

But the point is: if x is nan, then a correct representation of nan appears to stand in x. That is the first assertion that I seek to have verified, and the second assertion is: when such disambiguous bit representation of nan stands in x, how do I generically implement isnan as to booleanly evaluate that fact.

But x can't be nan. You promised the compiler that, and if it were nan, it is allowed to skip the check (because it's not nan!), and allowed to do a lot of nonsensical stuff. It's a little like checking for overflow after the overflow. You've already entered a universe in which a false thing is assumed to be true.
